# how to use multiple if statement in blade file in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

In laravel5 instead of using `foreach` I can use the if statement to filter the data on the basis of SQL query. How can I view my page using `ifelse` statement in laravel5? I have three `div` class in these class how to fetch the data from the database? How to use in the blade.php file?

How can I filter the data from database using routes and controller?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="block-content block-content-small-padding">
<div class="block-content-inner">
<h2 class="center">Recent Properties</h2>
<ul class="properties-filter">
  <li class="selected"><a href="#"  class="all" data-filter="*"><span>All</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"  class="featured"    data-filter=".featured" ><span>Featured</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="rent" data-filter=".rent" ><span>Rent</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"class="sale" data-filter=".sale" ><span>Sale</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="properties-items isotope"  style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 810px;">
<div class="row ">
@if($val -> $value)
<div class="property-item col-sm-6 col-md-3 isotope-item my " style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
  <div class="property-box">
    <div class="property-box-inner">
      <h3 class="property-box-title"><a href="#">{{$value->city}}</a></h3>
      <h4 class="property-box-subtitle"><a href="#">{{$value->state}}</a></h4>
      <div class="property-box-picture">
        <div class="property-box-price">{{$value->property_price}}</div>
        <div class=""> <a href="#" class="property-box-picture-target"> <img src="images/test/{{$value->image}}" alt=""> </a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@elseif($val -> $value)
<div class="property-item  col-sm-6 col-md-3 isotope-item"  style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
  <div class="property-box">
    <div class="property-box-inner">
      <h3 class="property-box-title"><a href="#">{{$value->city}}</a></h3>
      <h4 class="property-box-subtitle"><a href="#">{{$value->state}}</a></h4>
      <div class="property-box-picture">
        <div class="property-box-price">{{$value->property_price}}</div>
        <div class=""> <a href="#" class="property-box-picture-target"> <img src="images/test/{{$value->image}}" alt=""> </a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@else($val -> $value)
<div class="property-item property-sale   col-sm-6 col-md-3 isotope-item myButton my"  style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
  <div class="property-box">
    <div class="property-box-inner">
      <h3 class="property-box-title"><a href="#">{{$value->city}}</a></h3>
      <h4 class="property-box-subtitle"><a href="#">{{$value->state}}</a></h4>
      <div class="property-box-picture">
        <div class="property-box-price">{{$value->property_price}}</div>
        <div class=""> <a href="#" class="property-box-picture-target"> <img src="images/test/{{$value->image}}" alt=""> </a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Controller:

```
  public function index()
    {

        $view=DB::table('property_details')

        ->get();
        return View::make('index', array('val'=>$view));        

     } 

     public function rentshow()
    {  
        $show=DB::table('property_details')
        ->where('sale_or_rent','=','rent')
        ->get();
        return View::make('index', array('val'=>$show));        

     }

     public function saleshow()
    {  
        $show=DB::table('property_details')
        ->where('sale_or_rent','=','sale')
        ->get();
        return View::make('index', array('val'=>$show));        

     }
```

Comment: Multiple if statement is no different in blade than just regular php. Currently your if statements are incorrect. You should be using controller to filter data and pass it to your view. You didn't post any of your controller so it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am agree with @CanCelik. Please post your controller code.

Comment: Let me explain I have a filter on my homepage with four Anchor tags like  All | Featured | Rent | Sale  now I am trying to filter the data from database, when user clicks on Rent only rent related data will come if clicks on All then all data will come , remember i have stored these values(featured , sale, rent) in my DB column. Static Html filter is working Fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your `if` / `else` statements to:

```
@if ( $val == "something" )
  // do something
@elseif ( $val == "something-else" )
  // do something else
@else
  // the default
@endif
```

You can't pass a condition to `@else` like you've done in your code.